# Finding a controller that minimizes an integral function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

I am trying to solve an optimal control problem where we are given a control system

$$ \dfrac{d}{dt}\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1\\ 1 & 3\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 3\\ 5 & 5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \end{bmatrix}
$$

with the initial condition $\mathbf{x}(0)=[3,1]^T$ and it asks me to find a controller, with $u_1$ and $u_2$ in $[0,+\infty] \to \mathbb{R}^2$, that minimizes the following integral function

$$\int_0^\infty \left( \mathbf x^T \mathbf{I} \,\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{u}^T \mathbf{R} \, \mathbf{u} \right) \mathrm d t $$

where

$$ \mathbf{R} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix} $$

I have done a couple control system problems but never one where I have to minimize a function, let alone an integral one so I am really lost on how to start. Does anyone know a good place to start or examples that solve similar problems?

Comment: The answer below appears to interpret it as if you want non-negative controls (which makes the problem much harder), but if  $[0,+\infty] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ simply means you want a control policy for $t\geq 0$, then this is nothing but linear quadratic control, which is a standard state-feedback control strategy, available with lqr(A,B,Q,R) in MATLAB for instance.

Comment: although you will have to remove the redundancy in the controls and define $u_{tot} = u_1 + u_2$, as the lqr command does not like this algebraic dependency.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg But the cost term for the control is $u_1^2 + u_2^2 + u_1 u_2$ which I think can't be expressed in terms of $u_{tot}$ since $u_{tot}^T R_{tot} u_{tot} \neq u^T R u$ for any (in this case scalar) $R_{tot}$?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is related to the field of optimal control. The first thing that we notice is that the control input is symmetric in the system equation and in the cost function. This means that only the sum of $u_1$ and $u_2$ matters not the individual values Hence, we can simplify the problem by introducing $u=u_1+u_2$

$$\dot{x}=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&3 \end{bmatrix}x+\begin{bmatrix}3\\5 \end{bmatrix}u \text{ , with } x(t=0)=[3,1]^T \text{ and } \lim_{t\to \infty}x(t)=0.$$

Our goal is to minimize

$$J= 1/2\int_0^\infty x^T(2I)x + u\cdot 2\cdot u\,dt.$$

In general, if we have the system

$$\dot{x}=Ax+Bu\text{ , with } x(t=0)=x_0,\text{ and } \lim_{t\to \infty}x(t)=0.$$

And if we want to minimize the cost

$$J = \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{t=0}^{\infty}x^TQx + u^TRu \, dt$$

We will have to solve the algebraic Riccati equation (short ARE) for the symmetric matrix $P$

$$-P^{}A^{}-A^TP^{}-Q^{}+P^{}B^{}R^{-1}B^TP^{}=0.$$

Then solve for the optimal state

$$\dot{x}^*(t)=[A-BR^{-1}B^TP^{}]x^*(t), \text{ with } x^*(t=0)=x_0.$$

The minimizing control law is given by

$$u=-R^{-1}B^TR^{}x^*(t).$$

If the obtained solution does not satisfy $u\geq 0$ for all $t$, then you will need to use [Pontryagin's maximum principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin%27s_maximum_principle), which is a little bit more difficult than the unconstrained problem.

**Reference:** The best reference that I know for optimal control is the book Optimal Control systems (Naidu). In my opinion, it is one of the best books on control systems in general. Highly recommend buying a copy :D.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this so clearly. Just to clarify, the book uses the notation $u:[0,+\infty]$ to mean time from $0$ to $+\infty$ so $u$ is not necessarily constrained. I think I should have phrased it more clearly. Not sure if that changes anything. Thank you again

Comment: Also would you be able to explain the reasoning behind why $1/2$ was factored out of the integral constraint?

Comment: @Notorious776: $u:~[0,\infty)$ is confusing. You should not adopt this notation and rather use $t\in [0,\infty)$. The one half is just there to have better-looking equations. This comes from the fact that a quadratic form $x^TQx$ has the gradient $2Qx$. You could drop it but then your equations would not look as simple as they do.

Comment: thank you for the clarification and I will keep in mind proper notation for the future. One obstacle I am running into is R not being invertible making it tough (impossible?) to solve for P in the Ricatti equation. Do you have any suggestions on how I can proceed?

Comment: @Notorious776: In my reformulation, $R$ is a scalar with the value $2$ so $R^{-1}=1/2$.

Comment: I see. Sorry but I have one more clarification question: should the last line be $u=-R^{-1}B^TR\dot{x^*}(t)$ instead of $u=-R^{-1}B^TRx^*(t)$ since the line before solves for $\dot{x^*}$?

Comment: No, it is not dotted. We need to solve the previous equation for $x^*(t)$ not the derivative.

Comment: How would we go about finding $\dot{x^*}$ to be able to solve for $x^*$ in that case?

Comment: It is a linear-time invariant differential equation. it has constant coefficients an can be solved by finding the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and eigenvectors $v_i$ of the system matrix $[A-BR^{-1}B^TP]$ The solution is given by $x^*(t) = c_1v_1\exp(\lambda_1 t) +c_2v_2\exp(\lambda_2 t)$. You can find the coefficients $c_1$ and $c_2$ by using the initial condition.